# after inserting elements to my Bst it always saves the last 3 elements when i try to search in Bst it search only in the last 3 elements

Tags: java, insert, binary-search-tree

After adding an elements to the Bst its only saves last 3 elements when i try to search an element it only search in the last 3 elements

I'am trying to add elements to my Bst and it added all the elements i ask to added but when i try to search in elements its always search in the last 3 elements
in my code there is an add function that i call for inserting the elements and for searching iam using contains function that return true or false if the element is found ... after adding some elements , i tried to search for element in the first 3 elements and in the last 3 elements it finds it but when i search in more than 3 elements its only check in the last 3 , i tried to debug then i saw its only check in the last 3 elements that added, even when i try to add element that is already in the tree , if the element in the last 3 elements it return false but if its not it return true like , again checks only in the last 3 elements
my code:

`code:`

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    BstNode root;
    private int sizeoftree=0;

    // Binary Search Tree Node
    class BstNode {
        T val;
        BstNode left, right;

        public BstNode(T val) {
            this.val = val;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }
    }




public BinarySearchTree() {
        this.root=null;
    }

    public int size(){
        return sizeoftree;
    }



public boolean add(T val) {         
         if (this.root == null) {
                this.root=new BstNode(val);
                sizeoftree++;
                return true;
            }
            while (this.root != null)
            {
                if (val.compareTo(this.root.val) < 0) {
                    if(this.root.left==null)
                    {
                        this.root.left=new BstNode(val);
                        sizeoftree++;
                        return true;
                    }
                    this.root = this.root.left;
                }
                else if(val.compareTo(this.root.val) > 0) {
                    if(this.root.right==null)
                    {
                        this.root.right=new BstNode(val);
                        sizeoftree++;
                        return true;
                    }
                    this.root = this.root.right;
                }
                if(val.compareTo(this.root.val)==0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            
            return false;
    }
    


public boolean contains(T val) 
    {
        return search(this.root, val);
    }
    
     
     private boolean search(BstNode root, T data) {
            if (root == null) {
                return false;
            } else if (root.val.compareTo(data)==0) {
                return true;
            } else if (root.val.compareTo(data) > 0) {
                return search(root.left, data);
            }
                 return search(root.right, data);
            
        }





public static void main(String[] args)
{
    BinarySearchTree<Integer> tree = new BinarySearchTree<Integer>();
    tree.add(5);
    tree.add(4);
    tree.add(2);
    tree.add(3);
    tree.add(6);
    tree.add(1);
    tree.contains(5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you change the `root` of the tree, and misuse it for navigating down the tree, thereby losing the reference to what should remain the actual root of the tree. The *only* time the `add` method should assign to `this.root` is when the tree is empty:

```
 this.root=new BstNode(val);
```

All other times you have an assignment to `this.root`, it is wrong.

So instead of statements like this:

```
this.root = this.root.left;
```

...you should use a local variable (let's say `current`), which you should initialise as

```
BstNode current = this.root;
```

...and which you should then use for navigating through the tree with statements like:

```
current = current.left;
```

Once you understand this issue, you should be able to update your code consistently.

Comment: after fixing the code the code works fine thanks :)